# Various brackets on mathmode

Tags: equations, brackets

How do you write a code on LaTeX do to something like

[image]

Note that on the left there is a bracket (not captured on the photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dcases` and `rcases` from the `mathtools` package. Then you mess around with the `\\[]` to make the right space available

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{dcases}
\begin{rcases}
x=x\\
y=y\\
\end{rcases} &\text{if } a<0 \\[3ex]
\begin{rcases}
z=z\\
w=w\\
\end{rcases}&\text{if } a\ge 0\\[0.1ex]
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result is achieved using the `dcases*` environment which defaults the second column to normal "roman" text, so it will allow to insert text freely, as suggested by GustavoMezzetti. This keeps a neat logical division between the equation part (left) and the "explanation" part. You'll have to surround the math expressions contained in the second column with `$`, though

here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{dcases*}
\begin{rcases}
x=x\\
y=y\\
\end{rcases} &if $a<0$ \\[3ex]
\begin{rcases}
z=z\\
w=w\\
\end{rcases}& if $a\ge 0$\\[0.1ex]
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `dcases*` instead of `dcases` is more straightforward then repeatedly saying `\text{...}`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes, but it's just an "if" and I would've to put extra `$` to typeset the `a>0` parts

Comment: I *would exactly* say `... & if $a>0$,\\...`: in my opinion, it’s the *logic* of the markup that matters, not the number of keystrokes… :-)